# How does a website remember not to store cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, website, cookies

A popup on a website showed up, and asked me if I allowed the website to store preferences in cookies. By accident, I said "no". Refreshing/restarting does not bring the popup back.

Is there a default way to get these kind of popups back, without clearing history/cookies?

Also, how can a website remember if it is allowed to store cookies? By storing it in a cookie?

Comment: Cookies for storing the preference of users regarding the storage of cookies are exempt from the European laws that mandate web sites not to store cookies without user permission.

Comment: @user2428118 I would be interested in (official) references supporting that. Thanks

Comment: @dbjohn http://ico.org.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies mentions that cookies involving user interface customization are exempt. Since a popup is a UI element, this probably falls under that exemption.

Comment: IANAL, but it seems like a loop hole. Section 3.6 in [Opinion 04/2012 on Cookie Consent Exemption](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2012/wp194_en.pdf) says that "They are 
only set if the user has explicitly requested the service to remember a certain piece of 
information, for example, by clicking on a button or ticking a box. " If you explicitly request the service not to store cookies, then it shouldn't store cookies...

Comment: @dbjohn I found [this Dutch web site](https://cookierecht.nl/diensten/juridisch-advies/cookie-toestemming/geen-toestemming-nodig/) of a bureau specialized in IT related juridical counsel. Basically, for "essential" cookies there is no permission requirement. A cookie storing cookie preferences can be considered an essential cookie.

Comment: @dbjohn There's a technical issue here and that's that HTTP is by design not stateful (doesn't remember anything about browsers). Cookies were invented to address this issue, and therefore you absolutely need something like 'essential' cookie in order to even remember that user doesn't like cookies. Some newer browsers have "don't track me" feature, but that's still not widely used.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They asked you if you'd like to **store preferences** in cookies, not whether you'd like them to set cookies in general. So if I were writing support for this feature, I'd set a separate cookie (e.g., `nopref`) and check whether user has this cookie. There is a good chance you'll find such a cookie for that site, which you can clear without clearing other cookies or history.

**Inspecting cookies set for a particular page**

In Firefox, you can list cookies for a particular page by right-clicking a blank part of the page, then selecting **View page info** option. You'll find a "View Cookies" button in the "Security" tab. In Chrome, you have the same "View page info" option, which opens a dialog that hangs from the address bar. Link near the top will take you to a listing of cookies. I assume similar features can be found in other browsers.

**Discovering if site sets a cookie**

Here's one way you can discover what the site is doing. Open the site in Incognito mode. Open developer tools and switch to Network tab. Then check out what activity is happening in the background as you decline to have the site track you with cookies. Specifically, look for response headers and see if there are any 'Set-Cookie' headers in there. Then try deleting cookies mentioned in the header and see if that makes any difference.

**About localStorage**

Since another poster has mentioned localStorage (in-browser database), I'll comment on that as well. I think it'll be very rare that the site uses localStorage for this purpose as localStorage data isn't accessible to the server unless there is JavaScript code that sends the data back to server. If you wish to check the contents of the localStorage, the fastest way is to open the developer tools in your browser, go to (JavaScript) Console tab, and type `localStorage`. This should give you an output that looks something like:

```
Storage { someKey: "value", length: 1 }
```

The `someKey` identifies the value set by JavaScript on the page you are on. If you believe `someKey` does something relevant, you can try removing it by running the following:

```
localstorage.removeItem('someKey');
```

This removes the data under `someKey` key from the localStorage, and reloading the page may restore it to 'factory settings'. If you're not sure if the particular key is set by the cookie notification functionality, you may open the page in incognito mode, and list the contents of localStorage before and after interacting with the page.

Again, I doubt too many sites use localStorage for this purpose.

Answer (score 9):

Because this sounds an awefull lot like dutch sites and your name seems dutch, I'm going to expand a little:

In the EU it is required you give some heads up to the user that you are using cookies. All it takes is a small message, a section in the disclamer, or a one-time pop-up (those are rare). *Sometimes* there is an opt-out possibility

The Netherlands like to be the best behaved boy in class, so we upped it a nudge:
All **non-essentional** cookies are forbidden, unless the user opts in (oppesite of the EU regulation).

This creates a problem, what is essential? Well, that's pretty much covered, concluding that even every site that uses google analytics places a non-essential cookie.

They fix this with a user-unfriendly (but so far the 'best' solution) cookie-choice wall.
Before you have any access to the site, you have to click [ok] or [nope]. This has to be done before the pageload, because e.g. Google Analytics.

There are multiple solutions to remembering this. One is saving the IP in a database, or the local storage of the browser (like a clientside database), but the most simple solution is to save this in.... a cookie.
This is allowed, because this is an essential cookie.

**Resetting those settings**
Because they'll likely go for a local storage solution (the client's DB, or a cookie), you can go to your history (ctrl+H) and rightclick the website, then select [forget]. This will remove everything related to this site, including it's cookies and storages.

**Regarding the 'this law is dead in UK' comment**
In the Netherlands this isn't really getting implemented anymore. The indication (the EU-version) is still getting shown, but the opt-in hardly exists, apart from the mayor sites.

Comment: Martjin, there are legit reasons why you wouldn't want to be tracked with cookies.  In general your answer is good, however I would try reworking the last paragraph or removing it.

Comment: FYI [this law is basically dead in the UK](http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/the-stupid-cookie-law-is-dead-at-last/). It won't be enforced, ever.

Comment: I've been wondering for a bit now, why the downvote?